# Array Formula for SUM IF in a row of a table that require "Greater Than"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs, cumulative-sum

Hi i am looking over this issue in the other threads but i dont think this ever questioned before.

I want to use Array Formula of SUMIF to work as bank balance. Here is the data sample:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O3dlXVtehg2nNuMgkaFGv7rHx7KEyiOq1QyD7yHBLi4/edit#gid=0

Basically, i know this will work:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF((B8:B11)&(C8:C11),B8&(C8:C11),D8:D11))
```

But i dont know how to make this work:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF((B8:B11)&(C8:C11),("<="&B8:B11)&(C8:C11),D8:D11))
```

I want a formula that sum every transaction BEFORE each date of each transaction IN THE SAME BANK and that works like arrayforumula that automatically return any data below it without us having to re-create or copying formulas when new data is added.

Well, this sounds complicated, but hopefully anyone understands. But just look at the link and you will understand.

Comment: you said "i don't think this ever questioned before".  For future reference what you're describing is a very common request, often searched for as a "cumulative conditional sum."

Comment: Okay thankyou MattKing for letting me know, I am new to this. Pardon for the noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 (TRANSPOSE(ROW(C2:C))>=ROW(C2:C))*
 (C2:C=TRANSPOSE(C2:C)), D2:D, 0))), ROW(C2:C)^0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow thankyou for the answer, it helps a lot. But one more thing is lacking, the formula doesnt take any regards on date. Sorry i forgot to mention that the date is also important. 

Is the formula adjustable to the version where we can take regard of the date? Like, the balance only adding any value with the date smaller than itself.

Comment: can you explain the date logic in more detail or with some example in your sheet?

Comment: So, the balance doesnt sum any value I which date is greater than the date of the balance. I have updated the link, you can check.

I need that because sometimes the date is not sorted.

Comment: Oh i found out how to solve my date problem. Thankyou so much for the reference! It works like magic!